# Provide links to official style guides when writing questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

The answers to many questions tagged [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) on CodeReview start with or otherwise include references to [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python Style Guide. Many reviews include comments on use of whitespace (e.g. around operators and arguments), variable naming conventions, etc., all of which are addressed in this document.

Is it possible to add a reference to this Style Guide when the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag is used, within the **Ask a Question** page itself? It would reduce on the duplication of content in the answers and allow the reviewers to focus more on what the code does than how it's laid out. Something like:

> It looks like you are writing a question about some [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) code. Consider applying the guidelines in the [Official Style Guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) before submitting your code for review.

Users who have already read and followed the style guide can ignore it, but it might prove useful to those who aren't yet aware of it.

I'm sure there are similar documents for other languages that could also be referenced in the same way, although I am aware that some languages have more than one school when it comes to these style conventions.

Comment: Have you seen the tag wiki? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python/info there already is a link to the PEP-0008

Comment: @Vogel612 I have, but that doesn't seem to be part of the typical question-asking flow (it is usually two clicks away: [tag:python] > [read more...](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python/info)).

Answer (score 2):

```js
clippy.load('Clippy', function(agent) { agent.show(); agent.play('Writing'); agent.speak("It looks like you're trying to be helpful, but that could get a bit annoying."); agent.play('Explain'); agent.speak("Also, the goal of Code Review is to offer custom critiques, not to parrot advice blindly."); agent.play('CheckingSomething'); agent.speak("Sometimes, it makes sense to break the PEP8 rules."); agent.play('GetAttention'); });
```

```css
.clippy, .clippy-balloon { position: fixed; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; top: 100px; left: 150px; } .clippy-balloon { background: #FFC; color: black; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; } .clippy-content { max-width: 200px; min-width: 120px; font-family: "Microsoft Sans", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; } .clippy-tip { width: 10px; height: 16px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAgCAMAAAAlvKiEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAlQTFRF///MAAAA////52QwgAAAAAN0Uk5T//8A18oNQQAAAGxJREFUeNqs0kEOwCAIRFHn3//QTUU6xMyyxii+jQosrTPkyPEM6IN3FtzIRk1U4dFeKWQiH6pRRowMVKEmvronEynkwj0uZJgR22+YLopPSo9P34wJSamLSU7lSIWLJU7NkNomNlhqxUeAAQC+TQLZyEuJBwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat; position: absolute; } .clippy-top-left .clippy-tip { top: 100%; margin-top: 0px; left: 100%; margin-left: -50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smore-inc/clippy.js/7ca9b150ad214e1110eabcd847fa3d409cd0df6e/build/clippy.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not saying everyone should *"blindly follow"* anything; as PEP-8 itself opens *"a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds"*. However, it seems pointless to have so many repeats of the same points, which can trivially fixed with existing tools (or at least encourage people to say *why* they've *chosen* to ignore it, if they have). If anything, having so many questions with basic style issues *obscures* the custom critiques you are rightly keen on.

Comment: ahhh Clippy. How you've not been missed at all. Best use of Stack Snippets to date.